# Why is max an empty sequence in python

Tags: python, max

I am a fairly experienced coder, but I am not able to understand this problem within python. The text file that it refers to is laid out as

```
Jeff 4 7 7
Rich 2 1 9
Chris 4 6 5
```

Yet when I run the code it works out the first two sets of data but not the last. The code is:

```
with open(classno, 'r') as f: #it doesn't write last score and 
        for line in f:
            nums_str = line.split()[1:]
            nums = [int(n) for n in nums_str]
            max_in_line = max(nums) #uses last score of it need to combine
            print (max_in_line)
            with open('class11.txt', 'r') as f:
                parts = line.split()
                if len(parts) > 2:
                    name = str(parts[0])
                    f = open(classno, 'a')
                    f.write(("\n") + (name) + (" ") + str(max_in_line))

        f.close()
```

...but on the final line of the text file it says:

```
max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Comment: no offence, but an experienced developer would do some *trivial* debugging, like `print line`

Comment: Note that `max() arg` is different from `max`. The latter is a builtin function; the former is the *argument given to* that function. The error is stating that you've given an incorrect argument, not that `max` itself "is" an empty sequence (which would make no sense). (Also, in your last sentence, ideas would be *helpful* or *welcome*; your *response* to these ideas might be "gratefulness", but the ideas themselves aren't expressing gratitude, which is what the word "grateful" means.)

Answer (score 4):

Probably you have a newline character at the end of your file, so you're reading in a blank line.  Try this:

```
for line in f:
    if line: 
        ....
```

Answer (score 3):

You redefine `f` in the most outer `with`

```
with open(classno, 'r') as f:
```

In inner loop:

```
with open('class11.txt', 'r') as f:
```

Give different names to these vars.

Comment: Plus `f.close()` should not be explicitly called. `with` takes care of that.

Comment: @dfsfsdfdsfs  Also, opening in `r` mode doesn't allow writing, which is what's being done.